# While concatenating array, giving error

Tags: python, numpy

Code:

```
import numpy as np;
import joblib

var=np.zeros((4, 4))
var1=np.zeros((4, 4))

va=np.concatenate(var,var1)

joblib.dump(va, '/media/ab/AB-3/file_name.dat')

aa=joblib.load('/media/ab/AB-3/file_name.dat',None)

print aa
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ab/Pictures/store.py", line 6, in <module>
    va=np.concatenate(var,var1)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Can you formulate a question? Did you try to understand the issue? Did you read the documentation of the `concatenate` function to know how to specify the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

look docs http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

```
va=np.concatenate((var,var1),axis=0)
```